# Preciso de ajuda com replaceAll para valores monetarios!

Tags: java

```
String sal = "1500,32";
double salario = 0;
sal.replaceAll( ",", ".");
salario = Double.parseDouble(sal);
```

Alguém pode me explicar melhor o replaceAll? está dando erro!

Answer (score 3):

O `replaceAll` retorna uma `String` e não altera a atual. Você precisa fazer o seguinte para o seu código funcionar:

```
String sal = "1500,32";
double salario = 0;
sal = sal.replaceAll(",", ".");
salario = Double.parseDouble(sal);
```

Porém tenha em mente que há formas melhores de converter valores monetários.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo cara!

Comment: @JoelMedeiros não esqueça de aceitar a resposta para que possa ajudar outras pessoas com dúvida similar.